# Multiplication on floating numbers returns unexpected result

Tags: c#, floating-point, double

```
int countBouncy=5;
int count=999899;

double percent = (double)(countBouncy / count) * 100.0;
```

The result of that phrase is unexpected, I get zero.

Why won't it work?

Comment: It works fine, really. Your expectation is wrong however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing an integer division on `(countBouncy / count)`. Change your code to

```
double percent = ((double)countBouncy / count) * 100.0;
```

That way, `countBouncy` is converted to `double` explicitly and `count` is converted to `double` implicitly by the c# compiler to make it compatible to the (now `double`) `countBouncy`.

Otherwise `(countBouncy / count)` is calculated as `(5 / 999899) --> 0` since both are integers.

---

How does integer division work? Let's take an example:

```
7 / 2 = 3
```

Integer division drops the decimal part that a real division would yield. The result is truncated towards zero. You can get the remainder of this division by using the modulo operator

```
7 % 2 = 1
```

and perform the backward calculation  like this

```
2 * (7 / 2) + 7 % 2 = 7
```

You can enter this in the immediate window of Visual Studio to test it:

> ?2 * (7 / 2) + 7 % 2<enter>
>   7

Comment: Are you sure you meant `int percent`?

Comment: I meant `double percent`. Probably I copy pasted an early erroneous version. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Because your division is integer division, which results in 0, which you *then* cast into a double.

Your current code is effectively the same as:

```
int temp = countBouncy / count;  // == 0
double percent = (double)temp * 100.0;
```

Do you cast on one of the items first:

```
double percent = ((double)countBouncy / count) * 100.0;
```

That will cause your division to be done in double precision up front.

Answer (score 2):

When you divide an `int` by an `int`, the result is always an `int`, so it's going to round down to the nearest integer (zero). Try this instead:

```
((double)countBouncy / count) * 100.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your numerator and denominator are both `int`s.  Hence, the resulting quotient is an `int` which C# calculates by rounding down to 0.  Plus, you are trying to assign a `double` type to an `int` type.  In order to achieve your desired result, do:

```
double percent = ((double) countBouncy / count) * 100.0;
```